# How do I access my Angular2 App from another system after upgrading to 2.0.0

Tags: angular, cors

When working with Angular2 RC5 and below I have never had a problem accessing my application from another computer. My home environment is such that I run 1 Angular2 app on a MacMini that acts as my central application and a 2nd Angular2 app on my laptop to act as my local application. These 2 apps talk to each other in multiple ways but the user all needs to access both apps from the browser.

This has worked just fine for months, but after upgrading my Angular2 app on the Mac Mini to the 2.0.0 Release I can no longer access the application from my laptop. It works fine accessing via localhost on the mini itself.

Is there a setting or launch parameter required to make the application available beyond just localhost access?

I'm not sure I even know where to look for this in my code...

Comment: How do you start the app?

Comment: ng serve --live-reload false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng serve` default is to listen on localhost(127.0.0.1) only. To make it listen on all interfaces:

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Just waiting for SO to let me ;)